# Ofuscar un numero

Tags: laravel, codificación, ofuscación

Hola amigos estoy en un proyecto en el cual vamos a emitir cupones.

Lo que necesito hacer es tener un ID de cupón. Y este mismo ofuscarlo.

Ejemplo

Cupón: ADD-000-031

Los últimos 6 dígitos son el ID del cupón. 
Lo que necesito es que se creen números aleatorios y que no se repitan para que los pueda asignar a un cupón y con este recuperar su id.

Ejemplo de como quedaría.

Cupón: ADD-597-145 Cupón sin ofuscar ADD-000-001

Cupón: ADD-234-012 Cupón sin ofuscar ADD-000-002

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacer esto.
Por el momento lo resolví de la siguiente manera.

```
$code = "N"
do {
    $a = str_pad(rand(0,999999), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $code = $code . $a;
} while (\App\Models\Cupon::where('Barcode', $code)->count() >= 1);
```

Es poco elegante y eficiente dado que tengo que consultar a la base de datos para estar seguro de que no existe el código ahí. Lo que quiero es que pueda ofuscar directamente el ID y después lo pueda desofuscar para encontrar el id, y no tener que escribirlo en otro campo duplicando mi ID . (CuponID, Barcode).

Comment: el id identifica al cupón? si guardas el código como key funcionaría como ID, para generar códigos que no se repitan podes usar timestamp, randombytes y firmarlos con un hmac

Comment: Tal vez sería más fácil que generaras una clave al azar con str_random() y guardas el id de ese str_random() en la base de datos.  Igual como te comentan arriba para que el cupón sea único puedes meterle el timestamp. Igual esto te puede ayudar: https://hashids.org/php/ ,https://github.com/jenssegers/optimus

Comment: Si el ID identifica al cupón, Tienen algún ejemplo como terminan siendo los 6 dígitos aleatorios y únicos para poder meterlos como ID. Actualmente saco números aleatorios entre el 0 y el 999999, Compruebo que no este en base de datos y luego lo inserto. Por eso no me gusta esta solución aun que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos años necesité hacer algo así y desarrollé un package para esto.
No lo he migrado a las nuevas versiones de Laravel pero según lo que recuerdo debería funcionarte.
[Laravel Integer Hashids](https://github.com/amamarul/integer-hashids)

Este paquete lo que hace es generar un hashid basado en el id de la tabla pero el id son solo números enteros.

```
  encode(1548);
  // output: AA-7988887798

  decode('AA-7988887798');
  // output: 1548
```

El hashid de una tabla puede ser igual al de otra pero si utilizas la funcionalidad que te puse de usar prefijos ahí se solucionaría ese problema. E incluso podes crear varias conexiones para que cada tabla tenga su integer hashid.

Me he basado en otros packages y las colaboraciones son bienvenidas.

Espero te sirva.

Los pasos son simples y están bien explicados en el repositorio pero para cumplir con las políticas de SO los escribo acá y lo pongo en español.

### Instalación

#### Usando Composer require

```sh
$ composer require amamarul/integer-hashids
```

#### Agregar Service Provider en el archivo config/app.php

```php
Amamarul\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider::class,
```

#### publicar archivo de configuracion

```sh
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Amamarul\Hashids\HashidsServiceProvider'
```

### Modo de uso

1. definir las configuraciones en el archivo config (`config/hashids.php`)
   Podés crear diferentes conexiones con diferentes parametros

```php
    'default' => 'main', // nombre de la configuracion por defecto. si no especificas ninguna se toma esta
    'prefix-separator' => '-',// si usas un prefix podes optar por agragarle un caracter de separacion

    '<Name Connection>' => [
        'salt' => 'your-salt-string', // un texto cualquiera
        'length' => '10', // cuantos caracteres debe tener el hashid
        'alphabet' => '0123456789', // que caracteres queres usar. podes poner tambien letras ademas de numeros
        'prefix' => null, // deja en null si no queres usar un prefijo sino defini uno. Ej 'PRE'   El hashid sera elgo como PRE-1234567891
    ],
```

2. con conexion 'main' sin prefijo (`'prefix' => null`)

```php
  use Hashids;

  Hashids::encode(1548);
  // output: 7988887798

  Hashids::decode('7988887798');
  // output: 1548
```

3. Con 'main' connection y con prefijo (`'prefix' => 'AA'`)

```php
  use Hashids;

  Hashids::encode(1548);
  // output: AA-7988887798

  Hashids::decode('AA-7988887798');
  // output: 1548
```

4. con conexion 'custom' y sin prefijo 'prefix'

```php
  use Hashids;

  Hashids::connection('custom')->encode(1548);
  // output: 7988887798

  Hashids::connection('custom')->decode('7988887798');
  // output: 1548
```

5. Si preferís usar inyección de dependencias en lugar de Facades podes hacer lo siguiente usando el `HashidsManager`:

   - con conexión 'main'

```php
  use Amamarul\Hashids\Support\HashidsManager;

  class Foo
  {
      protected $hashids;

      public function __construct(HashidsManager $hashids)
      {
          $this->hashids = $hashids;
      }

      public function encode($id)
      {
          $this->hashids->encode($id)
      }

      public function decode($hashid)
      {
          $this->hashids->decode($hashid)
      }
  }
```

- con conexion  'custom'

```php
  use Amamarul\Hashids\Support\HashidsManager;

  class Foo
  {
      protected $hashids;

      public function __construct(HashidsManager $hashids)
      {
          $this->hashids = $hashids->connection('custom');
      }

      public function encode($id)
      {
          $this->hashids->encode($id)
      }

      public function decode($hashid)
      {
          $this->hashids->decode($hashid)
      }
  }
```

### Helpers

Podés usar tambien los helpers 'encode()' y 'decode()'
- encode()

```php
  // con conexion  'main'
  encode($id)
  // con conexion  'custom'
  encode($id,'custom')
```

- decode()

```php
  // con conexion  'main'  
  decode($hashid)
  // con conexion  'custom'  
  decode($hashid,'custom')
```